# Live Edit - Intellij, Expressjs, nunjucks

Tags: node.js, express, intellij-idea, jinja2, nunjucks

Currently unable to get the template views updating with Intellij Live Edit within a Node expressjs app using nunjucks.

Debug configuration:

[image]

Configuration in **Settings -> Build Execution, Deployment -> Debugger -> Live Edit**:

[image]

When I make changes to the JavaScript code and refresh the browser the changes **are** reflected.

Making changes to the nunjucks template within "views" (index.njk) e.g.:

[image]

....then refreshing the browser, the changes **are not** reflected...

Any help appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: As mentioned by Iena, this feature is not currently supported. A feature request has been raised https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-36297?p=IDEA-215683 - feel free to upvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Live editing Jinja2 templates is not currently supported. If you miss this feature, please file a feature request to youtrack, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB

Comment: No the answer I wanted ;-) but thanks for the reponse. I'll file I feature request.